# I can not find the sound folder in the executable but if it finds it in the IDE

Tags: java-8, wav, javax.sound.sampled

I have a script that does not find the sounds folder when I created the `.exe`. On the other hand, in the IDE it locates the `.wav` files without problems.

My sound folder is on the same level as the source folder. I do not have errors in the IDE.

What can it be?

Comment: Which IDE? This question is tagged JAVA-8, what are you using to build the (windows?) .EXE ?

Comment: I build with Launch4j. [link](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) cause my scrpits dont lunch in.JAR.  Is a console Chat.